# Angular typeahead like directive with multiple datasets?

Tags: angularjs

The angular-ui typeahead directive doesn't support multiple datasets.  Is there another popular directive that supports this feature?  Screenshot of what I'm after: [image]

Comment: I don't think so. I tried to search for typeaheads myself and didn't find many implementations. The best thing to do would be find a non-angular version and make a directive out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own. See my comment here about native typeahead implementation using only angular: [Using Bootstrap typeahead with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680296/using-bootstrap-typeahead-with-angular/30945399#30945399)

You could merge all your data into one array, then edit the template in the directive to separate sources in the list