# Bootstrap dropdown-menu keyboard navigability

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a nice and **big** dropdown menu (world countries) in my angularjs+bootstrap app.
I would expect I could use a *keyboard* alphabetical key to faster scroll the menu.

For example, hitting <kbd>J</kbd> I'd like to scroll to `Jamaica` entry...

[image]

Does a way to implement exist already, or I should think forking dropdown-menu?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good stackoverflow article, **[Using Bootstrap typeahead with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680296/using-bootstrap-typeahead-with-angular)**, that has an answer that would likely help your cause.  Using some version of a typeahead would work.  The top two answers should point you in the right direction.  Hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't absolutely think about `typeahead` for this problem (even if I did use it, beforehand...). Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I could not use a typeahead approach, since I want a pre-filled dropdown with all values, and then **scroll** to input value best match, not **filtering** out non matching elements... :-(

Comment: @MarcoS well, worth a try at least.  If I can think of anything else, I'll let you know.